# How to override text of edit text when maxLength of edittext is 1

Tags: android, one-time-password

For example: I enter 1 in edittext then again if i type 2 in same  edittext then not want to remove manualy 1 but want to override it directly from 1 to 2.

For Example:

```
    editTextOtpFirst.addTextChangedListener(this);
    editTextOtpSecond.addTextChangedListener(this);

      @Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


    if (editTextOtpFirst.getText().length() ==1 && !checkEditTextEmpty(editTextOtpFirst)) {

        editTextOtpSecond.requestFocus();
    }
    if (editTextOtpSecond.getText().length() ==1 && !checkEditTextEmpty(editTextOtpFirst) ) {
        editTextOtpThird.requestFocus();
    }

}




 @Override
  public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.editTextOtpThird) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {

                editTextOtpSecond.requestFocus();
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (v.getId() == R.id.editTextOtpFourth) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
                editTextOtpThird.requestFocus();
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (v.getId() == R.id.editTextOtpSecond) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {

                editTextOtpFirst.requestFocus();
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now when i enter value  "1" in edit text-1 then cursor move to the next edit text-2 but i want to change value of edit text-1 from "1" to "4" but need to remove manually "1" and then need to enter another value..but i do not want this...i want to direct override from "1" to "4" when i type another value in edit text.

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution would be using the edit text hint instead of text. You can set the hint color to whatever color you want the text to be. Then you can use the `setHint` method.

Comment: but i want to override the text which already  in edit text .When i enter second time in that edit text then previous one will override automatically.This is my question

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a `TextWatcher` by adding an `onTextChangeListener` to the edit text, something like this:

```
editText.addOnTextChangeListener(new TextWatcher{
 beforeTextChanged(..){
// ..... can try something here
}
onTextChanged(Charsequence text, ...){
// or can append the text to the editText here
editText.setText("");
editText.append(text);
}
});
```

Also i'm writing this code on the go so please look for proper syntaxing ps. the interface names are correct. Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

You can add this single line to your layout xml file, and android will do the stuff for you

```
android:maxLength="1"
```

you should add it as a property to the editText element, for example

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:maxLength="1" />
```

It's an old question, but I think this will work out fine.